# No change in output structure using pointers

Tags: c, data-structures

I am trying to learn the basic steps in data structures and recently, encountered a problem after executing a programme.

I am trying to call a "function by value" and "function by reference" (MARKED 1 & 2 in Comments in []).

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<string.h>


 struct date
 {
  unsigned int year;
  unsigned char month[30];
 };

 struct attendance
 {
 unsigned char name[30];
 long unsigned int record_no;
 double time;
 struct date d;

 }stu1;

 struct attendance change(struct attendance stu);
 void display(struct attendance);

      //<<  declaring function using pointer structure [1]
 void change_ptr(struct attendance *); //<<edit

 int main()
 {
      char ch;
      char buff[100];
      struct attendance stu2;


      printf("enter the name: \t record.no \t and time \n");
      scanf("%s%lu%lf",stu1.name,&stu1.record_no,&stu1.time);
      printf("\n");
      stu2=stu1;    //copied contents of structure 1 to 2
      stu1=change(stu1);
      display(stu1);

      printf("\n");
      printf("change using a pointer \n");
      printf("\n");

      change_ptr(&stu2); //<<function called  <<edit
      display(stu2);         //no change in output ???
      getch();

}


struct attendance change(struct attendance stu) //function by value 
{
     char tr[30]="good day ";
     char fp[50];

     stu.record_no +=1000;
     strcpy(fp,stu.name);
     strcpy(stu.name,tr);
     strcat(stu.name,fp);

     stu.time-=70.30;
     return stu;
}

void display(struct attendance stu)
{
printf("%s \n record.no = %lu \t time = %lf \n",stu1.name,stu1.record_no,stu1.time);
}

  //facing problem here;;

void change_ptr(struct attendance *p)// <<pointer function [2]
{
     strcat(p->name,"  welcome  ");
     p->record_no+=5000;
     p->time-=2000;

};
```

In the above programme I have used both "call by value" and "call by reference", and  I have no issue using the former one but when it comes to the latter function I seem to get the same output as the former call by value function.

Output

call by value

JAMES WELCOME<

XXXX ROLL NO

XXXX date

using pointer

Same as above  // function called by using pointer seems to be completely bypassed?

Comment: `change_ptr` : nothing code of return value.

Comment: Your concept of pass by ref/value is wrong. If the `change` functions were `void` functions, only the one where you pass a pointer would update the struct in `amin`. But if you return the struct, the struct in `main` is updated, of course.

Comment: I am quite confused..sorry, new to data structures and they are quite a headache especially with pointers.If you don't mind, can you show me an example.

Answer (score 1):

Your `change_ptr` function doesn't return anything, even though it is declared to return `struct attendance` so the result is undefined.

Besides, it doesn't really make sense to pass the pointer to the function AND return it as well as a copy anyway, but this is not your problem here.

Since you already pass a pointer, you can declare it void and still print the modified contents.

Comment: I have changed the function to                                    >>void change_ptr(struct attendance*p);  and called the function using change_ptr(&stu2); but still I am getting the same output no change

Comment: Please update the code to the current version. It's a bit hard to know what else is wrong without seeing what happens.

Comment: Devolus I have changed the code as you have suggested, edited the above code, show in comments"edit".